# My MacBook internal mic has stopped working

Tags: microphone

For no obvious reason the internal microphone has stopped working on my 2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 MacBook (2015) (running OS12.2).  I have disabled 'ambient noise reduction' and my 'input volume' is at maximum.  I've also tried enabling dictation and I've reset my PRAM.

Help please!

Comment: Have you run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)? Did it reveal a hardware problem?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.  I've run diagnostics.  No hardware problem detected...?

Comment: Darned if I know then. I still suspect a hardware defect, perhaps Apple Diagnostics doesn't get that granular. You might try restoring macOS. If that goes nowhere, I think you're left with taking it in for service.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90123/internal-mic-stopped-recording-voice-but-hears-case-keyboard-touching?rq=1) might suggest a solution.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - turns out the microphone had water damage and needed replacing ;-(

Comment: Good to know. How'd you discover the cause?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - that's what the fixer said.  There had been a spill a week or so earlier that I hadn't realised was so serious...